# add text to pandas dataframe plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas

I am plotting a dataFrame and I want to add information about the information (mean and std of the data)
I am plotting the data this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': lifeExpExcel['Country'], 'Infant mort. rate':
lifeExpExcel['Infant mort. rate']})
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',x= lifeExpExcel['Country'])
ax.set_ylabel('Infant mort. rate')
ax.set_xlabel('Country')
plt.show()
```

I want to add two string (val + name) to the plot
How can I do this?

btw if there's a better way to do the plot i'll like to know that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ax.text()` or `ax.annotate()`

`ax.text` accepts the x-coord and y-coord, and then the string (in data coordinates) as arguments. `ax.annotate` is a little more complicated: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/annotations_intro.html